# Angularjs REST retrieve PDF

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, pdf

I´m trying to retrieve a PDF file from my backend application, but I´m not getting it.

It looks like i´m not getting at my Java REST.

**EDIT**
It´s working now!

**JAVA REST**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/comprovanteInscricao/{id}")
public void get(@PathVariable String id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, NumberFormatException, AplicacaoException {
    ComprovanteInscricao comprovante = iComprovanteInscricaoManager.pesquisarPeloId(Long.parseLong(id));
    byte[] arquivo = comprovante.getArquivo();

    response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
    if (arquivo != null) {
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

            response.setContentType(PDF_MIME_TYPE);
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + id + EXTENSAO_PDF);
            response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(arquivo.length));

            IOUtils.write(arquivo, outputStream);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
        }
    } else {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

}
**Angularjs Service**

```
angular.module('concursosApp').factory('ComprovanteInscricao', function($http, API_URL) {

return {
    downloadPdf : function(id) {

        return $http.get(API_URL + 'api/comprovanteInscricao/' + id, {
            responseType : 'arraybuffer'
        }).then(function(response) {

            return response;
        });
    }
};
```

});
**Angularjs Controller**

```
$scope.imprimirComprovante = function (id) {
        ComprovanteInscricao.downloadPdf(id).then(function (result) {
            var file = new Blob([result.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            window.open(fileURL);
        });
    };
```

Thanks to advance!!

Comment: what is the exact problem your having with your code, if your have any error logs that your getting it would help

Comment: Console says that $http is not defined. But i believe that its not getting the JAVA REST anyway. Thanks.

Comment: are you injecting $http into your controller/service/factory? I mean the error is pretty clear

Comment: Do you mean `.controller('MinhaInscricaoController', function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, Inscricao, ComprovanteInscricao, transferObject)`?

Comment: hope that you have cross origin support enabled if communication happens between two domains (server and client)

Comment: If i do a console.log on API_URL in service, it shows the right path, but its going to the frontend path.